# Convert com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage to string

Tags: java, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I am retrieving a message from an IMAP server (Gmail), and trying to print it out, along with some information about it, ultimately to be stored in a string to be parsed later. I am printing out the following

```
System.out.println(message.getSubject());
System.out.println(message.getFrom()[0]);
System.out.println(message.getReceivedDate());
System.out.println(message.getContent().toString());
```

and this is what it prints out

```
Your Order with Amazon.com
"auto-confirm@amazon.com" <auto-confirm@amazon.com>
Tue Dec 30 23:14:01 EST 2008
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@6baa6838
```

The first 3 print out exactly what I am expecting, but the last one should be the entire message, should it not? If not, what do I need to do to get it to get the entire message as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAPMessage extends MIMEMessage, and according to [docs](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getContent%28%29), the `getContent()` method returns an Object. The type of object is NOT guaranteed to be a String. In your case, the Object that is returned is a `MIMEMultipart`. Check out this [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach) answer and its example ( msgshow.java) for how to handle a `MIMEMultipart` object.

Comment: Thank you for this. At this point, I wont be able to look at it again until monday, but when I do, I will probably wind up accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the MimeMultipart class doesn't implement the toString method.  I haven't tested this, but you could always try this.

```
((MimeMultipart)message.getContent()).writeTo(System.out);
```

Like pointed out in another post though, be careful because it is not guaranteed to always return the MimeMultipart.